# Extracting multiple columns from a column containing JSON text in KDB

Tags: kdb

I have a table which contains a column having JSON text. I want to parse that column and extract the different attributes to multiple columns.

```
c:([] date:2?.z.d ;  client:( "{  \"firstName\": \"John\",  \"lastName\": \"Smith\", \"age\": 27 }" ; "{  \"firstName\": \"Scott\",  \"lastName\": \"Tiger\", \"age\":29 }" ) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative method to create a single json array from the entire json column.

Running .j.k on a single string would be more efficient than running .j.k on many small arrays/dictionaries/strings.

```
// test table
q)c:([] date:2?.z.d ;  client:( "{  \"firstName\": \"John\",  \"lastName\": \"Smith\", \"age\": 27 }" ; "{  \"firstName\": \"Scott\",  \"lastName\": \"Tiger\", \"age\":29 }" ) );
// combine each string with "," and encompass in "[]"
// join each parsed dictionary with each row from c, keep client column for keep sake
q)c,'exec .j.k {"[",x,"]"}"," sv client from c
```

Often is the case with json capturing, that the data and messages are schemaless/unstructured. If that's the case and each json string doesn't necessarily have the same tags as others, then you can create a static map of your required output and join that map to each parsed json message. This will then have the affect of always resolving to a table. You can also type your map to ensure the resulting table is correctly typed.

```
// insert row with missing age tag and new location tag
q)`c insert (.z.d;"{\"firstName\": \"Sean\", \"lastName\": \"O'Hagan\", \"location\" : \"Dub\"}");
// name and locations are strings, age is float
q)map:{x,'first each x$\:()}[`firstName`lastName`age`location!10 10 9 11h];
// manually edit symbol nulls to be varchars, so when casting to symbol the RHS param is always a varchar
q).[`map;where map[;1]~\:`;:;(-11h;" ")];
// join map to each parsed dictionary, and delete client column as we have extracted useful data
q)delete client from c,'exec flip map[;0]$flip (map[;1],/:.j.k {"[",x,"]"}"," sv client) from c
date       firstName lastName  age location
-------------------------------------------
2004.02.01 "John"    "Smith"   27
2005.06.06 "Scott"   "Tiger"   29
2018.03.13 "Sean"    "O'Hagan"     Dub
q)meta delete client from c,'exec flip map[;0]$flip (map[;1],/:.j.k {"[",x,"]"}"," sv client) from c
c        | t f a
---------| -----
date     | d
firstName| C
lastName | C
age      | f
location | s
```

HTH, Sean

Answer (score 2):

If you execute .j.k on each json in your table you will be left with a list of dictionaries which is analogous with a table;

```
q)exec .j.k each client from c
firstName lastName age
----------------------
"John"    "Smith"  27 
"Scott"   "Tiger"  29
```

You can then join this to your original table and extract whatever data you like;

```
q)foo:(,'/)(c; exec .j.k each client from c)
q)select date, firstName, lastName, age from foo
date       firstName lastName age
---------------------------------
2008.02.04 "John"    "Smith"  27 
2015.01.02 "Scott"   "Tiger"  29
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to drop the client column after the data is extracted you could use the following function, which has 3 parameters - `x` the table, `y` the json column and `z` columns to extract:

```
q)f:{((),y)_x,'((),z)#.j.k'[x y]}
q)f[c;`client;`firstName]
date       firstName
--------------------
2008.02.04 "John"
2015.01.02 "Scott"
```

This can be broken down as follows: `.j.k'[x y]` will extract parse and the json data into a table using [`.j.k`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotj/#jk-deserialize), `((),z)#` uses the [take operator `#`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/lists/#take) to extract only the required columns, which are then joined to the original table with `x,'`. The final step is to [drop `_`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/lists/#_-drop) the json column with `((),y)_`.

The use of `(),` is required for both take and drop operations as they expect to be passed a list and this ensures that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Though JSON parsing has already been integrating in KDB '.j' namespace (3.3 and above).
It can be parse using `.j.k`.

```
select date, firstName:client@\:`firstName , lastName:client@\:`lastName from update .j.k each client from  c
```

You can use '.j.j' to serialize the kdb object to string representing JSON.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are not interested in keeping the client column as it is. This is how I would do it:

```
((),`client) _ c,'{.j.k x}'[exec client from c]
```

and you will get a table like this one:

```
date       firstName lastName age
---------------------------------
2003.07.05 "John"    "Smith"  27
2005.02.25 "Scott"   "Tiger"  29
```